# GPS Text Entry CCC

Tags: java

Ok, so i've been working on this problem of a past contest and i cant figure out what to do...
The question states that the program will calculate the number of cursor movements it takes to "type in" a phrase. For example, to enter the word "GPS" , starting from "A" you would move 1 down to select "G", then move 3 right and 1 down to select "P" and then move 1 down and 3 to the left to select "S" and at the end you would have to click "ENTER" so you would have to move 1 down and 5 to the right to select "ENTER". That's a total of 15 cursor movements.

http://wcipeg.com/problem/ccc08j3 -- thats the detailed problem

I honestly cant figure out the steps to even approach this problem. I was told not to overthink it as it is easy :/

Comment: How would you compute the difference from g to p?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is give every key two coordinates, one indicating the column, the other the row.

A = (0,0)
B = (1,0)
C = (2,0)
..
G = (0,1)
..
etc

Then, for successive key presses you calculate the difference in columns and the difference in rows. Add them up and the total will give you the number of cursor movements needed.